# DeX: separate app environment?

Tags: samsung-dex

I am looking for a way to have the same app on DeX as on phone but with different environment.

Goal is to have Chrome browser on both Phone and on DeX, but with different setting on phone than on DeX.

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "different environment" as one could run a Chromium based browser in DeX and a different browser (Google Chrome) when in phone mode.

Comment: Which one would be a Chromium based one for DeX? I just want to have different settings on DeX and phone.

Comment: The [Samsung Browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Internet) is built in. Searching for "Android chrome based browser" can give options if Samsung isn't acceptable.